# Tic-tac-toe with JS

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner and was hoping for some honest feedback on my js code. I struggled quite a bit on this, I did ask gpt to explain some concepts which I find it’s good for but wrote it all myself.

```js
// variable to store array of players 
const players = ['X', 'O'];
// declaring currentplayer with array index 
let currentPlayer = players[0];
let xScore = 0;
let oScore = 0;

// store cell class into cellElements 
const cellElements = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset');
const resultElem = document.querySelector('#results');

// array of possible win combinations  
const winningMoves = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]   
];

// for of loop to loop through each cell and add event listener 
for (const cellElem of cellElements) {
    cellElem.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}

// function to execute click in each cell 
function handleClick(event) {
    const clickedCellElem = event.target;

    // if else condition checking if cell is empty then inputting current play and switching between X and O     
    if (clickedCellElem.textContent === '') {
        clickedCellElem.textContent = currentPlayer;

        // calling checkWin function after each move 
        if (checkWin()) {
            resultElem.textContent = (`${currentPlayer} wins!`);
        // disable cell if win
            disableCell();
        } else if (checkDraw()) {
            disableCell();
            resultElem.textContent = (`It's a draw!`);
        }

        // if else condition to switch between the current player array index 
        if (currentPlayer === players[0]) {
            currentPlayer = players[1];
        } else {
            currentPlayer = players[0];
        }
    }
}

// check for a draw after no winning combinations 
function checkDraw(){
    for (const cellElem of cellElements)
    if (cellElem.textContent === '') {
        return false
    }
    return true
}


// function to execute when player wins by having 3 cells in a row with X or O
function checkWin() {
    // loops through each element in winning combinations 
    for (const winningMove of winningMoves) {

    // extracts individual elements into three separate variables to store the index of winnings combinations array 
        const [cellIndex1, cellIndex2, cellIndex3] = winningMove;
    // DOM grabbing html cell ID content of cells which corresponds to each winning combination index in array
        const cell1Content = document.getElementById(`cell-${cellIndex1}`).textContent;
        const cell2Content = document.getElementById(`cell-${cellIndex2}`).textContent;
        const cell3Content = document.getElementById(`cell-${cellIndex3}`).textContent;
    
        // condition to compare each 3 cells are the same to declare winner 
        if (cell1Content !== '' && cell1Content === cell2Content && cell2Content === cell3Content) {
            //increments player score 
            if (currentPlayer === players[0]) {
                xScore++;
                // displays the score getting DOM id element 
                document.getElementById("X-score").textContent = `[X] ${xScore}`;
            } else {
                oScore++;
                document.getElementById("O-score").textContent = `[O] ${oScore}`;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// function to reset the game
function resetGame() {
    //loop through cell elements 
    for (const cellElem of cellElements) {
        //reset the cells to empty string 
        cellElem.textContent = '';
        // add event listener again after cell disabled 
        cellElem.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }
    // reset result message 
    resultElem.textContent = '';
}

// Attach the resetGame function to resetBtn
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetGame);

//function to disbable the cells after win 
function disableCell() {
    for (const cellElem of cellElements) {
        cellElem.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top: 7rem;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    /* color: yellow; */
    color: #FFF01F;
    font-family: "Retro Gaming";
    border: 2px solid #88be19;
    padding: 10px;
    border-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E %3Cstyle%3Epath%7Banimation:stroke 5s infinite linear%3B%7D%40keyframes stroke%7Bto%7Bstroke-dashoffset:776%3B%7D%7D%3C/style%3E%3ClinearGradient id='g' x1='0%25' y1='0%25' x2='0%25' y2='100%25'%3E%3Cstop offset='0%25' stop-color='%232d3561' /%3E%3Cstop offset='25%25' stop-color='%23c05c7e' /%3E%3Cstop offset='50%25' stop-color='%23f3826f' /%3E%3Cstop offset='100%25' stop-color='%23ffb961' /%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E %3Cpath d='M1.5 1.5 l97 0l0 97l-97 0 l0 -97' stroke-linecap='square' stroke='url(%23g)' stroke-width='3' stroke-dasharray='388'/%3E %3C/svg%3E") 1;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #39FF14;
    font-family: "Retro Gaming";
}

.board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    max-width: 100%;

}

.cell {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF01F;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Retro Gaming";
    color: blue;
}

.cell:hover {
    background-color: #1a1b1c;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

h3 {
    border: 2px solid #88be19;
    color: #39FF14;
    padding: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Retro Gaming";
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.player-score {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: "Retro Gaming";
    color: #39FF14;
}

.reset {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
    color: #f55b1d;
    font-family: "Retro Gaming";
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.reset:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/4c19fc875e7ba1e6831129de3ab5ac0b?family=Retro+Gaming" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce">Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
    <header class="container">
        <div class="player-score" id="X-score">[X] 0</div>
        <h3>Scoreboard</h3>
        <div class="player-score" id="O-score">[O] 0</div>
    </header>
    <h2 id="results"></h2>
    <div class="board">
        <div class="cell" id="cell-0"></div>
        <div class="cell" id="cell-1"></div>
        <div class="cell" id="cell-2"></div>
        <div class="cell" id="cell-3"></div>
        <div class="cell" id="cell-4"></div>
        <div class="cell" id="cell-5"></div>
        <div class="cell" id="cell-6"></div>
        <div class="cell" id="cell-7"></div>
        <div class="cell" id="cell-8"></div>
    </div>
<div class="button-container">
    <button class="reset">New Game</button>
</div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are only a few things I would change with your JS

##### `if/else` vs `switch`

```js
if (checkWin()) {
  resultElem.textContent = (`${currentPlayer} wins!`);
  // disable cell if win
  disableCell();
} else if (checkDraw()) {
  disableCell();
  resultElem.textContent = (`It's a draw!`);
}
```

This part is repetitive and low-performing. If you have 2 if statements then you are nearly always better off with a switch statement. In this specific case, I would change the code completely:

```js
switch (true) {
  case checkWin():
    endGame(`${currentPlayer} wins!`);
    break;
  case checkDraw():
    endGame(`It's a draw!`);
    break;
  default:
    break;    
}

function endGame(text) {
  disableCell();
  resultElem.textContent = text;
}
```

This will perform faster for most browsers and you remove the repetitive code as in both cases you write a result message and disable all cells.

##### `if/else` vs `ternary` vs `modulus`

You have another `if/else` statement block that could be simplified as it is repetitive again.

```js
if (currentPlayer === players[0]) {
  currentPlayer = players[1];
} else {
  currentPlayer = players[0];
}
```

The most obvious change would be the usage of a `ternary conditional operator`:

```js
currentPlayer = players[currentPlayer === players[0] ? 1 : 0];
```

You use a ternary to check the condition within the assignment with following syntax:

> condition ? true : false

```js
const players = ['X', 'O'];
let currentPlayer = players[0];

function changePlayer() {
  currentPlayer = players[currentPlayer === players[0] ? 1 : 0];
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(currentPlayer);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changePlayer()">change player</button>
```

Another method would be the usage of a `modulus` here. However you would need to change the logic here to output the index number with `currentPlayer`:

```js
const players = ['X', 'O'];
let currentPlayer = 0;

function changePlayer() {
  currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % players.length;
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(players[currentPlayer]);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changePlayer()">change player</button>
```

##### return `true/false` vs `!` (not) statement

You have a line with an `if` statement to return the negated condition.

```js
if (cellElem.textContent === '') {
  return false
}
return true
```

In this case, you check a condition and want to return `true` if it is return `false`. The same vice-versa.
It can be simplified;

```js
return !cellElem.textContent === '';
```

A condition will already return `true` or `false` So you simply negate the condition with a `not` or `!`.

You could also do a double negation on `textContent.length` to check if the element is empty or not:

```js
function checkTextContent(cellElem) {
  return !!cellElem.textContent.length;
}

console.log(checkTextContent(document.querySelector('#element-1')));
console.log(checkTextContent(document.querySelector('#element-2')));
```

```html
<div id="element-1">Test</div>
<div id="element-2"></div>
```

---

Overall you have a good understanding of how to use `if/else` conditions but lack the knowledge about other more suitable methods and when to use them.

Comment: Instead of using `%`, toggling between two players could also be done using `1 - currentPlayer`

Comment: @TobySpeight I totally agree. This is coming from more abstract cases where you potentially have more than 2 players. Or instances that you want to infinitely iterate through an array.  I hope that he just remembers when he has to iterate though a larger array that you can also use the modulus.